# Secure HTTP trigger for Cloud Functions for Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

Is there a way to check if a user is firebase-authorized before triggering a cloud function? (Or within the function)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to protect firebase Cloud Function HTTP endpoint to allow only Firebase authenticated users?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42751074/how-to-protect-firebase-cloud-function-http-endpoint-to-allow-only-firebase-auth)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Yes. You will need to send the Firebase ID token along with the request (for example in the `Authorization` header of an AJAX request), then verify it using the Firebase Admin SDK. There is an [in-depth example](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/authorized-https-endpoint) in the Cloud Functions for Firebase samples repository. It looks something like this (made shorter for SO post):

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const cors = require('cors')();

const validateFirebaseIdToken = (req, res, next) => {
  cors(req, res, () => {
    const idToken = req.headers.authorization.split('Bearer ')[1];
    admin.auth().verifyIdToken(idToken).then(decodedIdToken => {
      console.log('ID Token correctly decoded', decodedIdToken);
      req.user = decodedIdToken;
      next();
    }).catch(error => {
      console.error('Error while verifying Firebase ID token:', error);
      res.status(403).send('Unauthorized');
    });
  });
};

exports.myFn = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  validateFirebaseIdToken(req, res, () => {
    // now you know they're authorized and `req.user` has info about them
  });
});
```

Comment: Hi @michael-bleigh, Is there a way to validate calls from our server using firebase admin sdk?

Comment: Is it possible to get a promise from `cors`? Function would be killed if we didn't return a promise.

Answer (score 1):

Since the question asks for auth-based access (1) within, or (2) **before** a function, here's an method for the "before" case: >

Since every Firebase Project is also a Google Cloud Project -- and **GCP allows for "private" functions,** you can set project-wide or per-function permissions *outside* the function(s), so that only authenticated users can cause the function to fire.

**Unauthorized users will be rejected before function invocation**, even if they try to hit the endpoint.

Here's documentation on [setting permissions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/managing-access-iam#controlling_access_on_a_function) and [authenticating users](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating).  As of writing, I believe using this method requires users to have a Google account to authenticate.

Comment: i'm finding trouble with this, i set to allow invocation from allauthenticated users but still when testing get http 403 are you sure this is how these functions work?