# How to get Firebase ID Token if using signInWithCustomToken?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

referring to [Secure HTTP trigger for Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43238611/secure-http-trigger-for-cloud-functions-for-firebase), as I'm signing into Firebase with a custom token using `signInWithCustomToken`, may I know where I can retrieve the Firebase ID Token so that I can make secure HTTP calls to Cloud Functions for Firebase? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve the Firebase ID token: 
With the user object returned by `signInWithCustomToken` 
do

```
user.getToken().then(function(token) {console.log('Firebase ID token', token})
```

Detailed information can be found here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User