# How to secure http cloud functions made from own server?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I've seen some examples about how to secure api calls made by authenticated user ([Secure HTTP trigger for Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43238611/secure-http-trigger-for-cloud-functions-for-firebase), [How to protect firebase Cloud Function HTTP endpoint to allow only Firebase authenticated users?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42751074/how-to-protect-firebase-cloud-function-http-endpoint-to-allow-only-firebase-auth/42752550)). But my problem is that I need to call these endpoints also from my server (in which I implement my custom token authorization). Is there a way to secure calls from my server? Maybe generating a token for it or whatever?

Comment: Nothing? Like Nothing?