# add token to endpoint for goolge cloud function python

Tags: python, flask, google-cloud-functions

I am working with google cloud functions in python and I am facing the following difficulties: 
I don't know how to add a token to the automatically generated endpoint for my HTTP cloud function : 
Below is the code I deployed :

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_httpauth import HTTPBasicAuth

auth = HTTPBasicAuth()
PROJECT = "projectname"


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['PUT', 'POST'])
@auth.login_required
def httpfunction(request):
    data = request.stream.read()
    return data
```

The generated URL is :

https://europe-west1-projectname.cloudfunctions.net/httpfunction

I want to add a token to it in order to avoid inappropriate persons to make use it , so basically here I want to avoid POST and PUT requests from unauthorized users. 
Any ideas how to do this please ?

Answer (score 1):

`HTTPBasicAuth` is not using tokens but username and password. To query the endpoint with username and password you should first modify your code to something like this:

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_httpauth import HTTPBasicAuth

auth = HTTPBasicAuth()

users = {
    "Obama": "WhiteHouse1",
    "Trump": "WhiteHouse2"
}

@auth.get_password
def get_pw(username):
    if username in users:
        return users.get(username)
    return None

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['PUT', 'POST'])
@auth.login_required
def httpfunction(request):
    data = request.stream.read()
    return data
```

Than you can query the endpoint with providing the username and password. For example a query with `cURL` would look like this:

```
curl -u Trump:WhiteHouse2 -X POST https://europe-west1-projectname.cloudfunctions.net/httpfunction
```

For queries using tokens, take a look at `HTTPTokenAuth`.

Look into the Stack Overflow thread [Secure Google Cloud Functions http trigger with auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46358013/secure-google-cloud-functions-http-trigger-with-auth) for other ways of authentication when using Cloud Functions. Implementation is described in Node.js but the idea can be implemented with python as well.