# What is the best practice to authenticate over firebase functions another server?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I want to call my firebase function HTTP API from another server -- which does not have an email and password (or any other firebase authentication method).

I want to be able to run a task like read/write in Firestore, however still protect the API. I would like to create some sort of programmatic keys like AWS does for calling their APIs. But, how to do this in firebase ? How can we generate such programmatic keys to communicate between one server to another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the best available option that you might try - because it doesn't seem to have an official way to do it - it's by using API keys to perform the verification and security of your calls. As clarified in the official documentation [Using API Keys](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys), this is not supported by all Google applications, but Cloud Endpoints should work.

Considering that, you can use Cloud Endpoints in integration with your Cloud Functions, to provide security via API keys. You can find more information on how to achieve that in this article [here](https://medium.com/google-cloud/secure-cloud-run-cloud-functions-and-app-engine-with-api-key-73c57bededd1).

Another alternative you may want to try, it's using a JWT token - as clarified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46924504/12767257) - as a header in your API calls. This way, you will be working with authetnication via keys - not exactly as in AWS, but it's a start - so you can secure your calls. :)

Anyway, if you don't find this useful, I would recommend you to raise a Feature Request in [Google's Feature Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187195&template=0), so they can check about the possibility of further implementation in such functionality.

Let me know if the information helped you!