# What Is The Right Way to Call A Google Cloud Function via A Next.js (with Typescript) App?

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-platform, next.js, google-cloud-functions, google-oauth

The component that I have doing an API call looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';

class Middle extends React.Component {
    handleClick() {
        console.log('this is:', this);
      }
    // This syntax ensures `this` is bound within handleClick.  // Warning: this is *experimental* syntax.  handleClick = () => {    console.log('this is:', this);  }

    async fetchNonce() {
        const response = await fetch("http://localhost:<PORT NUMBER HERE>/path/to/endpoint")
        console.log(response.status)
        const data = await response.json()
        console.log(data)
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <div className="col-md-12 text-center">
            <Button variant='primary' onClick={this.fetchNonce}>
                Click me
            </Button>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }

export default Middle;
```

The above code works for a simple throw away local node that I'm running for testing purposes. I want to use the above code to, instead of running a local function, reach out to Google Cloud Functions and run one of my Google Cloud Functions instead.

I created a Google Cloud Platform account, and made a simple hello_world type Python "Cloud Function" that just spits out some simple text. I made this function "HTTP" accessible and only able to be called/authenticated by a "Service Account" that I made for the purpose of calling this very function. I generated a key for this "Service Account" and downloaded the json file for the key.

I've seen a lot of tutorials on how to call functions via an authenticated "Service Account" but I'm concerned that a lot of methods might not be secure or following best practices. What is the best practices way to modify the above code to call a Google Cloud Function and authenticate with my "Service Account?"

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the thread [Ans1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46924504/15774176) and [Ans2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60044590/15774176):

> **1**. You can set project-wide or per-function permissions outside the function(s), so that only authenticated users can cause the
> function to fire, even if they try to hit the endpoint. Here's Google
> Cloud Platform documentation on [setting permissions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/managing-access-iam#controlling_access_on_a_function) and
> [authenticating users](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating). Note that, as of writing, I believe using
> this method requires users to use a Google account to authenticate.
> **2**. JWT token passed in in the form of an Authorization header access token. implementation in Node:
>
> ```
>     const client = jwksClient({
>     cache: true,
>     rateLimit: true,
>     jwksRequestsPerMinute: 5,
>     jwksUri: "https://<auth0-account>.auth0.com/.well-known/jwks.json"}); .
>
>   function verifyToken(token, cb) {
>   let decodedToken;
>   try {
>     decodedToken = jwt.decode(token, {complete: true});
>   } catch (e) {
>     console.error(e);
>     cb(e);
>     return;
>   }
>   client.getSigningKey(decodedToken.header.kid, function (err, key) {
>     if (err) {
>       console.error(err);
>       cb(err);
>       return;
>     }
>     const signingKey = key.publicKey || key.rsaPublicKey;
>     jwt.verify(token, signingKey, function (err, decoded) {
>       if (err) {
>         console.error(err);
>         cb(err);
>         return
>       }
>       console.log(decoded);
>       cb(null, decoded);
>     });
>   });
> }
> function checkAuth (fn) {
>   return function (req, res) {
>     if (!req.headers || !req.headers.authorization) {
>       res.status(401).send('No authorization token found.');
>       return;
>     }
>     const parts = req.headers.authorization.split(' ');
>     if (parts.length != 2) {
>       res.status(401).send('Bad credential format.');
>       return;
>     }
>     const scheme = parts[0];
>     const credentials = parts[1];
>
>     if (!/^Bearer$/i.test(scheme)) {
>       res.status(401).send('Bad credential format.');
>       return;
>     }
>     verifyToken(credentials, function (err) {
>       if (err) {
>         res.status(401).send('Invalid token');
>         return;
>       }
>       fn(req, res);
>     });
>   };
> }
> ```
>
> Google Cloud Functions now support two types of authentication and
> authorization: Identity and Access Management (IAM) and OAuth 2.0.
> Documentation can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating).

To gather more information about cloud functions with a JWT token passed in in the form of an Authorization header access token, you can refer to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating#exchanging_a_self-signed_jwt_for_a_google-signed_id_token).