# Firebase: How to programmatically generate a jwt token for a particular user similar to ` firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken(false)`?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, jwt

I have a http Cloud Function that expects a jwt token to be passed in the Authorization header (similar to Will's answer in this question: [How to protect firebase Cloud Function HTTP endpoint to allow only Firebase authenticated users?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42751074/how-to-protect-firebase-cloud-function-http-endpoint-to-allow-only-firebase-auth/42752550)).  This cloud function verifies the token with the function `admin.auth().verifyIdToken(<token>)`.  In my client code, I use the code `firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken(false)` to generate a token to include in the http request in the aforementioned header.

I want to be able to generate this token given a user's uid programmatically, preferably in Node, so that I can write tests for my function without having to go through my web app to get the token.

I tried using `admin.auth().createCustomToken(<uid>)` but that doesn't create a token that can be verified with `admin.auth().verifyIdToken`.  I also tried following the steps in this guide https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/auth, however the token generated is not one that `verifyIDToken` accepts, though I am able to make REST calls to the database using it (as mentioned in the guide).

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this?