# Firebase Authenticated HTTP Endpoints - Cloud Functions, are they Secure?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

So, I've seen this post: [How to protect firebase Cloud Function HTTP endpoint to allow only Firebase authenticated users?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42751074/how-to-protect-firebase-cloud-function-http-endpoint-to-allow-only-firebase-auth)

Essentially the HTTPS endpoint validates that it's from an `authorized use by ensuring Bearer token/Firebase ID is in the Authorization HTTP header.`

**I'm wondering, if someone found this Firebase ID, wouldn't this HTTP endpoint be compromised?** Ie, they could pass a bearer token with `Authorization: Bearer <Firebase ID Token>`

I've seen other methodologies which would use the Firebase realtime database as an API itself which might be more secure.

Curious if I'm missing something here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously, you should take caution not to expose these tokens.  But you should know that these tokens [expire after 1 hour](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/issues/31) and need to be refreshed by an authenticated client.  This happens automatically when using the Firebase SDKs.  So, even if someone were to capture one of these tokens due to careless application design, it would have very limited usefulness in the real world.

Comment: Excellent, perfect, that was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you

Comment: Would you also be able to elaborate on what would dictate careless application design in this context :)

Comment: Take extra care not to expose that token anywhere.  No one predicts the mistakes they make.