# How to create data related to user in Firebase Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I use anonymous user in my app and have a function that create `user` with only `uid`

```
export const createUserObject = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user, context) => {
  const userData = {"uid": user.uid}
  admin.firestore().collection("users").doc(user.uid).set(userData).then(writeResult => {
    console.log('User Created result:', writeResult);
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
});
```

Now I want to add another endpoint for user to create `note`. I plan to make note it own collection with 2 fields `content` and `uid` to reference back to user who create it.

Is there a way for Firebase function to retrieve `uid` for a triggered user? So I can write something like this, or I have to make user send it along with note?

```
export const addNote = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {

  if(request.method !== "POST"){
    response.sendStatus(404)
    return;
  }
  const content = request.body.content

  const data = {
    content: content,
    uid: HOW_CAN_I_GET_CURRENT_USER
  };

  let db = admin.firestore()

  return db.collection("notes").add({content: content}).then((ref) => {
     response.sendStatus(201)
  })
});
```

Comment: The user that triggered the HTTP function is available through `req.headers.authorization`. See this answer for a link to a sample: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42751074/how-to-protect-firebase-cloud-function-http-endpoint-to-allow-only-firebase-auth

Comment: You don't really need a cloud function for that. Firebase encourages manipulating data directly from the client, without the need for backend code. So you could create the notes the same way you create the user document.

Comment: @RicardoSmania so I create note and put uid on client side? Clients mange the relation themselves?

Comment: @sarunw yes, since you are already authenticating the user you can use the uid from the client. You should probably also define security rules so that users only see and change data they own.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Could you post your solution as an answer, please?

Answer (score 0):

The user that triggered the HTTP function is available through `req.headers.authorization`.

See this answer for a link to a sample, and another option using Callable HTTPS functions: [How to protect firebase Cloud Function HTTP endpoint to allow only Firebase authenticated users?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42751074/how-to-protect-firebase-cloud-function-http-endpoint-to-allow-only-firebase-auth)