# How to secure Firebase Cloud Functions based REST API

Tags: rest, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, api-key

When exposing a generic serverless, firebase cloud functions based REST API which can be used by customers (who will develop their own clients with their technology of choice), how to best secure it (Authentication / Authorization) and how to implement the security aspects?

Possible options:

- OAuth 2.0
- API Keys
- Using firebase's authentication in combination with cookies
- Others?

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42751074/how-to-protect-firebase-cloud-function-http-endpoint-to-allow-only-firebase-auth/42752550

Comment: @Neelavar: That's corresponds to the third bullet point above. However, this seems not ideal for an API, as this is based on a logged in Firebase user.