# Authentication for Cloud Scheduler calling Cloud Run service

Tags: google-cloud-run, google-cloud-scheduler

I got a Cloud Run service than executes some background tasks, and I need it to do so every 15 minutes.

I'm using a Cloud Scheduler Job, which perfectly fits my needs, to call the HTTP endpoint every 15 minutes, but I would also like to setup authentication to avoid external calls.

In the Job config page it allows me to add an auth header, but I cannot set an OAuth token because the service endpoint is not considered a Google service ( it does not end with "googleapis.com" ).

How am I supposed to handle Cloud Scheduler - Cloud Run authentication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you [define your Cloud Scheduler job via the CLI](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/scheduler/jobs/create/http)
you can manually [specify headers that you could use for authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42751074/how-to-protect-firebase-cloud-function-http-endpoint-to-allow-only-firebase-auth).

This allows more lightweight solutions than OIDC and OAuth.

Comment: This is actually what I ended up doing at the time, marking as accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

Cloud Run authenticates by validating OIDC token rather than OAuth token.

Please see this doc about how to set up for Cloud Scheduler:
https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/http-target-auth