# How to Firebase cloud function deploy privately

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

When i use `firebase deploy --only functions` to deploy cloud functions for firebase, i discover, that this functions are deployed with the authentication flag `allUsers`.

How can i deploy firebase cloud function with private by default as mentioned   [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60043024) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to set this access control level of Cloud Functions through the Firebase CLI. It currently indeed always sets the [access to allow all users](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/blob/4824697ea6ce25b8d907212ff5b46dfbba4d63d0/src/deploy/functions/release.js#L26-L34). It sounds like a reasonable request to allow control of this though, so I'd [file a feature request](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues) and possibly a PR on the repo.

For now: if you want to set this access level, you will have to do so in the Cloud console as explained in the Google Cloud documentation on [controlling access on a function](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/managing-access-iam#controlling_access_on_a_function).