Calling an authenticated Firebase Function from a chrome extension
I have a Firebase function that requires authentication per https://stackoverflow.com/a/44500591/82156:
exports.ping = onCall(async (request) => {
  if (!request.auth?.uid) {
    throw new HttpsError('permission-denied', 'Permission denied');
  }
  ...

I'm checking request.auth to ensure that the user is a registered user of my app per https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable?gen=2nd
I would like to call this function from a chrome extension. I followed https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/chrome-extension to create a firebaseAuth() function that uses an offline doc / iframe to let the user login via google. The authentication information is successfully returned from the function when I call it from my service worker.
However, when I make my call to my firebase function from my service worker, request.auth is not automatically set:
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
var firebaseApp = initializeApp( <firebaseConfig> );
import { getFunctions, httpsCallable } from "firebase/functions";

const functions = getFunctions();
const ping = httpsCallable(functions, 'ping');

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(async (message, sender, sendResponse) => {
  if (message.command === "pinginserviceworker") {
    const auth = await firebaseAuth();
    console.log('pinginserviceworker auth: ', auth);         // success
    const response = await ping();
    console.log('pinginserviceworker response: ', response); // 403
  }
});

If I manually curl a request and set -H "Authorization: Bearer <token> to the token I received above, the curl request works fine so I know the token is working.
Everything I've read says that the firebase sdk should automagically know that it's authenticated and pass the appropriate headers, but it's not, I think because the authentication is actually happening in the offscreen iframe rather than in the service worker itself.
How do I tell the firebase httpsCallable to use the auth token I received from firebaseAuth() when making calls?

It's not a great idea to mix a callable type function on the frontend with an HTTP type function on the backend (you need to use onCall instead of onRequest).  If you want to use a callable, both the frontend and backend should match types as shown in the documentation.  If you don't do that, either your frontend or backend is going to have to implement the spec that you get for free if they just matched as normal.

Good point. I updated the question to use onCall instead of onRequest. Now it's failing because request.auth is undefined when calling from the chrome extension, but it's successfully defined when calling from curl

I was able to workaround the problem by manually constructing my own fetch instead of relying on httpsCallable.
  if (message.command === "pinginserviceworker") {
    const auth: any = await firebaseAuth();
    console.log('pinginserviceworker auth: ', auth);

    const response = await fetch('https://<projectid>.cloudfunctions.net/ping', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${auth._tokenResponse.idToken}`
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ data: {} })
    });
    console.log('pinginserviceworker response: ', response); // 200 OK

  }

